# ElasticSearch 2.0 Java API aggregate filter with query_string

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Running on ElasticSearch 2.0 connecting via the Java API. I've got the following query working via the REST API and can't figure out how to do this using the Java API.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "myfield:*"
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "foo_low": {
      "filter" : {
        "query" : {
          "query_string" : {
            "query": "myfield:[1 TO 5]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "foo_high": {
      "filter" : {
        "query" : {
          "query_string" : {
            "query": "myfield:[6 TO 10]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've had a look at the examples using the `addAggregation` method but not sure how to pass in the `query_string` part.

As a bit of a background, was originally using Solr so have multiple Solr facet queries that need to be translated to ElasticSearch. The facet queries are a bit more complicated then I've shown in the example, with multiple fields and conditions referenced in each Solr facet query which is why I want to use the Lucene query with `query_string`.

Any ideas gratefully received! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like `myfield` is an integer field, you could use a `range` filter instead of a `query_string` which is more intended for text matching. Since you have two ranges you're interested in, I suggest to use the [`range` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) which allows you to define several range buckets (note that the `to` parameter is not included in the range). Your query would then go like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "myfield:*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "high_low": {
      "range": {
        "field": "myfield",
        "keyed": true,
        "ranges": [
          {
            "key": "foo_low",
            "from": 1,
            "to": 6
          },
          {
            "key": "foo_high",
            "from": 6,
            "to": 11
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Translated into Java code, it goes like this:

```
// 1. bootstrap the query
SearchRequestBuilder search = node.client().prepareSearch()
    .setSize(0).setFrom(0)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("myfield:*"));

// 2. create the range aggregation
RangeBuilder rangeAgg = AggregationBuilders.range("high_low").field("myfield");
rangeAgg.addRange("foo_low", 1, 6);
rangeAgg.addRange("foo_high", 6, 11);
search.addAggregation(rangeAgg);

// 3. execute the query
SearchResponse response = search.execute().actionGet();
```

** UPDATE **

As requested, here is the Java code that will generate the exact query you posted:

```
// 1. bootstrap the query
SearchRequestBuilder search = node.client().prepareSearch()
    .setSize(0).setFrom(0)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("myfield:*"));

// 2. create the filter aggregations
FilterAggregationBuilder lowAgg = AggregationBuilders
    .filter("foo_low")
    .filter(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("myfield:[1 TO 5]"));
search.addAggregation(lowAgg);
FilterAggregationBuilder highAgg = AggregationBuilders
    .filter("foo_high")
    .filter(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("myfield:[6 TO 10]"));
search.addAggregation(highAgg);

// 3. execute the query
SearchResponse response = search.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Thanks @Val - my actual Solr facet queries are more complicated and use multiple fields and conditions which is why I'd ideally like to use the lucene queries (with Solr I pass in the lucene query)

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I'll fix and let you know.

Comment: awesome! Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you, glad to help!